# Python Fabric script reports done but doesn't work properly

Tags: python, pyramid, fabric

I have the fabfile as per below.  When I manually ssh into the remote server and perform the commands exactly as per the fabfile, it works fine.  However, when I run the fabfile, it outputs the same progress as when run manually, reports no errors and exits with "done", but the last line doesn't actually work. Any advice would be great.

## Update:

After tailing the pserve log and try the fabfile a few more times, randomly it worked once.  Nothing had changed and when I ran it subsequently, it didn't work.  So I don't know what is going on.  Is it a timing thing?

Here is the code:

```
# kills a running pserve process and restarts it in daemon mode

from fabric.api import *

def deploy():
    pid = run("pidof -x pserve")  # works
    run("sudo kill -15 %s" % pid)  # works
    with cd('~/Repos/bessie'):
        run("sudo pserve development.ini --daemon")  # outputs "Entering
                                                     # daemon mode" but doesn't
                                                     # actually start the process
```

Output:

```
[ec2-xxx.ap-southeast-2.compute.amazonaws.com] Executing task 'deploy'
[ec2-xxx.ap-southeast-2.compute.amazonaws.com] run: pidof -x pserve
[ec2-xxx.ap-southeast-2.compute.amazonaws.com] out: 28998
[ec2-xxx.ap-southeast-2.compute.amazonaws.com] out: 

[ec2-xxx.ap-southeast-2.compute.amazonaws.com] run: sudo kill -15 28998
[ec2-xxx.ap-southeast-2.compute.amazonaws.com] run: sudo pserve development.ini --daemon
[ec2-xxx.ap-southeast-2.compute.amazonaws.com] out: Entering daemon mode
[ec2-xxx.ap-southeast-2.compute.amazonaws.com] out: 


Done.
```

Comment: What does pserve.log say?

Comment: The log says nothing.  Its as though nothing happens at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically just `sudo('pserve --daemon development.ini', pty=False)`. The pseudo TTY that fabric uses doesn't work very well for detaching processes.

http://docs.fabfile.org/en/1.5/faq.html#init-scripts-don-t-work

Side note, use supervisor, upstart or some other real process manager instead of `pserve --daemon`. If your process dies you'll have no real way of knowing using this seutp.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to:

```
 run("sudo....")
```

Fabric has a special method for that, `sudo()`.
So for one, you can rewrite that line as:

```
sudo("pserve development.ini --daemon")
```

Secondly, it looks like it's not fabric then, it's the `pserve` itself.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know about the `sudo` method.  Please see the update in my original question for more clues.